# EnableOAuth2Sso Access token expires after 1 hour of activity and UserRedirectRequiredException thrown

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have implemented SSO using **spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure 2.1.8.RELEASE** and it works fine on first launch. I am able to login and call my backend api.

After one hour of activity, the REST calls to my backend api fails due to UserRedirectRequiredException because the access token has expired and OAuth2RestTemplate is unable to refresh it. I get this stack:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:359)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
```

My App Configuration code is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Order(value = 0)
public class AppConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri}")
    private String userInfoUri;
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri}")
    private String userAuthorizationUri;
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String clientID;
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri}")
    private String preEstRedirectUri;
    @Value("#{'${security.oauth2.client.scope}'.split(' ')}")
    private List<String> scope;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String logoutUrl = env.getProperty("endSessionEndpoint") + "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(env.getProperty("homePage"), "UTF-8");

        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                    .antMatchers("/", "/static/**", "/webjars/**", "/login**", "/error**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(c -> c
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                )
                .logout(l -> l
                    .deleteCookies()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutUrl)
                );
        http.addFilterAfter(oauth2ClientContextFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(swqSSOFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
    }

    private Filter swqSSOFilter() {
    private Filter swqSSOFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter azureSsoFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(preEstRedirectUri);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails, oauth2ClientContext);
        azureSsoFilter.setRestTemplate(oauth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(userInfoUri, oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails.getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oauth2RestTemplate);
        azureSsoFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return azureSsoFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendRedirect(preEstRedirectUri);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
        OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
      registration.setFilter(filter);
      registration.setOrder(-100);
      return registration;
    }
}
```

I followed a lot of stackoverflow posts, but none of the solutions worked for me.
Can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Ranbir, To be specific in order to increase your token lifetime you need to implement refresh token in your code.Please refer [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-primary-refresh-token)

Comment: I added "offline_access" in the scope and "authorization_code" in the grant_type to get refresh token and use the right token service provider and apparently it solved the issue.

Comment: @Thanks for the update. I will move my answer from comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Moving answer from comments,*

To be specific in order to increase your token lifetime you need to implement refresh token in your code.Please refer [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-primary-refresh-token).